# Is there free VM software for Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, virtual-machine, virtualization

I've seen Parallels running Windows and it's pretty darn good.

But before I go and spend over $100 dollars, are there any free VM apps on the Mac that are up to speed?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[VirtualBox](http://virtualbox.org) is free and does a great job.

Comment: I second this, I have had only minor problems with VirtualBox.

Comment: I third this, the only problem that I've had is windbg integration for kernel debugging windows device drivers.  I do all my personal PC development on a mac w/VMware.  VMware is cheap for students . . . about $40.00 US or so.

Comment: I 14th this. However, I think the VirtualBox sharing (host to guest) is problematic. I usually use Windows sharing on my OSX host.

Comment: For as much as everyone on the internet bashes on it, virtualbox is surprisingly well done, all in all.  I had a couple of Virtual Box Machines (images) that I migrated onto my new XenServer an they ran flawlessly right out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

VirualBox does have an [OS X port for Intel Macs](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads), an it is free! I use it on Linux, pretty solid. I don't *think* it is compatible with VMWare images, but I <strike>could be</strike> am wrong. It IS!

Comment: actually, it is compatible with VMWare images; see my answer :)